# Update/Find by id limit

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mgo

When performing update/find only by _id should I specify $limit 1 or mongo already implicitly know that there will be only one record with specified id?

Answer (score 1):

yes there will always be unique _id in every document of a collection. An _id is made from following and therefore it is always unique and you will only find 1 document corresponding to one _id

```
a 4-byte value representing the seconds since the Unix epoch,
a 3-byte machine identifier,
a 2-byte process id, and
a 3-byte counter, starting with a random value.
```

Comment: I know that I will eventually find only one record but do I need to specify limit to 1 or it is already implicitly set when I am searching by _id? Becasue if I specify another field but _id, the system will keep on aggregating even though the document with the specified field was already found once.

Comment: know you have no need to specify limit 1 because _id is by default index so it will look in to the memory check the index and get the result for you it wont be doing a collection scan.

Comment: Thank you. This is the answer I was looking for.

Comment: Note that the *default* for [_id field](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#the-id-field) is [ObjectId](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/) value. However you can specify your own value i.e. int, string, etc as long as they uniquely identity the document within a collection. As mentioned `_id` is indexed unique and prevent duplication of entries.